# Jsoup, HTMLUnit, phantomJS: How can I click on Button OR fill out Formular TO bypass agecheck

Tags: java, phantomjs, jsoup, htmlunit

I collected URLs from a mainpage (Steam-GameStore) and want to call 
each single site, but some of them have an agecheck. I identified two 
different types of agechecks:

1. only a simple button is expected to click
2. a whole table has to be filled (with concrete specifications of your age)

Here are some pictures where to find it in the HTML-Code

[Agecheck type 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c19Ii.png)

[Agecheck type 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Vxt.png)

**My Question now is:**

How can I click on that damn button? In the way, that my for-loop 
(which is running through all that 11 thousands URLs) isn't breaking up 
and redirect me to that website BEHIND that agecheck (so I can read out data from it)?

I tried it with phantomJS, but this is JavaScript and I dont know how 
to include this in my Jsoup-Code. So I'm now trying to do that with 
HTMLUnit. Any ideas?

And then I have to fill up a whole form (for the complex
age-check). How can I do this? Is it possible to do this with HTMLunit?

Comment: Look at the network tab of the developer console - it should be sending out a request when you click it, which you can replicate in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. In short terms: I switched to Selenium WebDriver (for JavaCode) and Selenium IDE (FireFox Plugin).

________ Elaborately Description (step by step):

---

### 1. Install Selenium IDE for FireFox-Browser:

Go to:

!!!FUCK: I'm not allowed to post Links cause of my low reputation. Just want to do some good deeds, but was hindered (Fuck this world!) !!!

h**ps://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

(note: replace the two *  with t)

and click on "+ Add to Firefox"-Button. After rebooting Firefox, the 
installation will be done.
ATTENTION: It could be, that some errors will occure at this point (the "Selenium IDE"-entry doesn't appear in the menu of Firefox. If that so, 
try to install Selenium IDE by Firefox-> Add-ons->Plug ins: search for 
Selenium and select:

- Selenium IDE 2.9.1.1-signed"
- "Highlight Elements (Selenium IDE)"
- "Selenium IDE Button 1.2.0.1-signed.1-signed"
- Navigate in FireFoxMenu to : 
  Tools-> Web-DevelopmentExtras-> add new tools:
  (don't Know the exact term, cause I'm using german version of Firefox:
  -> Web-Entwickler->Weitere Tools laden)
  search for Selenium and choose:
  "SeleniumX"

After the Installation the "Selenium IDE"-entry appears in the firefoxMenu under: Tools-> Selenium IDE (german: Extras).

---

### 2. Install Selenium WebDriver for Eclipse / Dynamic WebProjects:

Got to:

!!!FUCK: I'm not allowed to post Links cause of my low reputation. Just want to do some good deeds, but was hindered (Fuck this world!) !!!

h**p://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#selenium_ide

(note: replace the two *  with t)

and download (first section on site): Selenium Standalone Server
=> version 3.0.1 (date: 11.5.16 [month-day-year])
After downloading the .jar-file, copy it to your  in 
Eclipse into the following folder:
NameofProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

Note: you could import this by "Build Path-> Configure Build Path", but I 
prefer this faster way.

Note: For creating a new "Dynamic Web Project" you have to install some 
new software in Eclipse: Help-> Install new Software: In the first line 
"Work with" choose: 
"Luna - FORBITTEN LINK for low REPUTATION-people" 
(for Eclipse Luna version, modify it to your Eclipse version!).
WAIT, til Pending... is done and then choose (last entry):
"Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development)

---

### 3. Using Selenium IDE to identify WebElement in HTML-Code by creating "Test cases" and export them as Java-Code to Eclipse:

Detailed Tutorial:

!!!FUCK: I'm not allowed to post Links cause of my low reputation. Just want to do some good deeds, but was hindered (Fuck this world!) !!!

h**p://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp

(note: replace the two *  with t)

3.1. Open FireFox-Browser: Go to WebSite you want to inspect / crawl / parse HTML-Code. Then (after page was loaded) open Selenium IDE (Tools-> Selenium IDE). Assure that the red button (looks like record-button in some Video-Tools) 
on the right most position in the menuBar (over "Table / Source"-Tabs) is 
activated (you can read a message by MouseOver). While recording, each 
CLICK on the Website you want to inspect creates automatically an entry 
into the "Table"-tab (a sort of simple Script-Command). Try to execute as 
many actions as you can / need on the website you  want to crawl, cause 
each action gives you the element in the HTML-code and helps you later to 
identify it by Java-Code!

3.2. After finishing your "inspectation" by simply MouseClicks, you have 
to save your "Test case" you created right now. 
File (F) ->Save Test Case: Choose a name you wish and confirm the save-
Process.

Note: the default StoreLocation for your Test cases is the "Mozilla-
FireFox"-folder on your PC (common path: C:\Programs\Mozilla Firefox).

3.3. Export the Test case as JAVA-CODE to Eclipse:

!!!!!  This  is the most awsome feature of Selenium IDE !!!!!

Now - after saving your Test case - go again in Selenium IDE to:
File (F)-> Export Test Case As:
choose: Java/JUnit 4/WebDriver: again FileChooser opens (default: 
FireFox-folder) and now you can save this "Export-File" as a Java-file.
IMPORTANT: the file ending has to be ".java" (e.g.: "IHateLowReputation.java").
Then copy / import it into your Eclipse-Project. Now you can open this 
.java-file and inspect the outwritten Java code for the rigth WebElements 
you want to find / choose / manipulate.
You can use this to get a feeling, how Selenium Webdriver commands in 
Java has to be coded. Copy the required Code-Lines to your Class.

---

### _____________ And here is my SolutionCode for my Problem above:

```
package fixWrongEntries;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptResult;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

import data.DB_Steam_Spiele;
import data.Spiel;

public class SolveButtonClick_FormSubmitt
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String agecheckButton = "Content in this product may not be appropriate for all ages, or may not be appropriate for viewing at work.";
    String agecheckKonkret = "Please enter your birth date to continue:";
    String noReviews = "There are no reviews for this product";
    try
    {
// turn off annoying htmlunit warnings
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
// Enabling JavaScript  => true in brackets
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
// Link for agecheck Typ 1 (simply Button click)
        String url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/324800/?snr=1_7_...";
// Link for agecheck Typ 2 (fill out formular and submitt)
//Stng url = "http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/72850/";
        driver.get(url);
//              System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2")).getText());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            /*********************************************************************
         *
         * Agecheck Typ 2
         *
             *********************************************************************/
            if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2")).getText().equals(agecheckKonkret))
        {
            System.out.println("Achtung: Agecheck konkret!");
// Fill out form with age-specifications:
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("ageDay"))).selectByVisibleText("18");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("ageMonth"))).selectByVisibleText("April");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ageYear"))).selectByVisibleText("1970");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // Click AgeCheck Formular Button: Fortfahren
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btnv6_blue_hoverfade.btn_small > span")).click();
                if(driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                System.out.println("Keine Reviews vorhanden!");
                continue;
            }
            else     if(!driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                String all =     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label"))
                        .getText();
                String steamPurchaser = driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label[2]")).getText();

                String communityURL =     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btnv6_blue_hoverfade.btn_medium"))
                        .getAttribute("href");
            }
        }

            /*********************************************************************
         *
         * AgeChecck Type 1
         *
             *********************************************************************/
        else     if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2")).getText().equals(agecheckButton))
        {
            System.out.println("Achtung: Agecheck Button!");
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn_grey_white_innerfade.btn_medium > span")).click();
                if(driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                System.out.println("Keine Reviews vorhanden!");
                continue;
            }
            else     if(!driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                String all = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label"))
                        .getText();
                String steamPurchaser = driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label[2]")).getText();
                String communityURL =     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btnv6_blue_hoverfade.btn_medium"))
                        .getAttribute("href");
            }
        }
            /*********************************************************************
         *
         * No Agecheck
         *
             *********************************************************************/
        else
        {
                if(driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                System.out.println("Keine Reviews vorhanden!");
                continue;
            }
            else     if(!driver.findElement(By.id("app_reviews_hash")).getText().contains(noReviews))
            {
                String all =     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label"))
                        .getText();
                String steamPurchaser = driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath("//div[@id='app_reviews_hash']/div[3]/div[2]/label[2]")).getText();
                String communityURL =     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btnv6_blue_hoverfade.btn_medium"))
                        .getAttribute("href");
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        System.out.println("Fehlermeldung aufgefangen");
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by)
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

I hope this will help people with a simular problem.